# Internet radio audio stream capture for Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, audio, ubuntu, streaming

Back in the olden days, I used to use [Winamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winamp) with [Streamripper](http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/) to capture streams to individuated, auto-numbered and -titled MP3 files. It was effortless.

For a long time now I've been on Ubuntu (or related) -- and now on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS -- and have been missing this feature. A scour of AskUbuntu suggests this is not so easy, and the (very few) solutions offered there don't work for me (the main options being the RadioBrowser plugin for Rhythmbox, or Streamtuner2 which does nothing on my system but launch an unpopulated gui).

So now I'm putting my hope in SoftwareRecs. What I need:

- Required

  - internet radio stream ripper for Linux/Ubuntu
  - *not* "network" (e.g. Shoutcast) specific, i.e. will open a URL input manually;
  - capture the stream as individuated files (not one big stream - VLC will do that);
  - free.
- Preferred

  - "monitor" stream while recording;<sup>1</sup>
  - auto-numbering and auto-naming can be customized.

Exists? I live in hope.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Streamripper for Winamp would play the stream as it wrote to disk in a single instance, playing the file from local source as it recorded, rather than having one stream being captured, and another stream being played.</sub>

Comment: I just read your 3rd bullet after writing a VLC answer. Man, thats a reminder to read questions carefully :( You might want to combine VLC with the tools here http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/16135/94 as I will do to achieve this result, sans the titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, after much looking, I simply tried Winamp + Streamripper (as in the question) under WINE in Ubuntu, and it has worked simply and flawlessly from 14.04, and now under 17.10. I still know of no other satisfactory solution, but so long as this works as well as it does, no other solution is needed.